# How many permutations will there be to this problem?

Tags: permutations

How many permutations of the following pattern will there be. The order has to stay the same. In other words, you can only swap the 'B' with another 'B' because it will not affect the pattern?

B C B C C B A B C A C

My guess is there are 5760 permutations. I worked with out by 'X' multiplying each permutation.** 24 (B) x 120 (C) x 2 (A)

Comment: Your answer seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

$4!*5!*2!=5760$

Just as you said.

Comment: Thank you sooo much - this would have kept me up all night.